# Android studio 3.6.3 not showing dependencies updates in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

Guys

Strange behaviour i have with the Android studio 3.6.3
Currently i work on two projects.
Only for the one of the projects, the studio highlights, whenever there is a new version for the dependencies in build.gradle file.

The both projects using the same gradle and build tools version.
There is no difference if i declare the dependency via exported constant or as a hardcoded string.

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:$rootProject.firebaseAnalytics"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0"
```

Currently i can't find what cause the problem.

Note:
I know that i can manually check the dependencies in Suggestions tab, but i want to fix the highlight functionality.

Comment: update android studio to 4.0 latest version.

Comment: @Mukuljangir I've updated to 4.0 still the same behaviour, this wouldn't help

Comment: above you are talking about 3.6.3

Comment: try to delete cache folder of android studio

Comment: @Mukuljangir Thanks for the comments, i've able to fix this. I've posted the solution as answer. Tnx again

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to fix this by enabling the "Obsolete Gradle Dependency" Lint check.

[image]